# wildcard character using like operator vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wildcard, vb-like-operator

I have a problem using "like" operator.

I want to find strings, in a table, like "Address #123" or "Address #56778" or "Address #2b". So, I wrote this in my code:

```
If m_Table.Rows(i).Item("NOTE").ToString Like "*ADDRESS #*" Then
```

But, the code reads the "#" as a wildcard, not a simple character.

How can I rewrite my code to make it read the # as a simple character, not a wildcard?

Comment: It made corrections to my questions, there are * wildcard used in the operator, because the address is stored somewhere in a "note" field. So, it doesn't start with "Address #"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can escape the special characters **[ ? # *** by enclosing them in square brackets **[ ]**. For more information see the [Like Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) reference.

```
If m_Table.Rows(i).Item("NOTE").ToString Like "*ADDRESS [#]*" Then
```

Another option is to use [StartsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw(v=vs.110).aspx), [EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) methods of the string class instead.

```
If m_Table.Rows(i).Item("NOTE").ToString().Contains("ADDRESS #") Then
```